# vectorTileLayerStyles based on properties issue

Tags: leaflet, style, vector-tiles

I'm trying to style some L.vectorGrid.protobuf tiles based on their properties, but I seem unable to find to get it to work.

```
var vectorTileOptions = {
            rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
            interactive: true,  // Make sure that this VectorGrid fires mouse/pointer events
            vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                'VectorTileFeature$2': function(properties, zoom) {
                    return {
                        weight: 2,
                        color: 'red',
                        opacity: 1,
                        fillColor: 'yellow',
                        fill: true,
                        radius: 6,
                        fillOpacity: 0.7
                    }
                },

            },

            getFeatureId: function(f) {
                console.log(f)
                return f;
            }
        };


var mapillaryLayerURL = window.origin + "/tiles/admin_countries/{z}/{x}/{y}"
var mapillaryLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(mapillaryLayerURL, vectorTileOptions)
```

this following prints the tile to console

```
getFeatureId: function(f) {
    console.log(f)
    return f;
}
```

and logs in the console:

```
VectorTileFeature$2 {properties: {…}, extent: 4096, type: 3, _pbf: Pbf, _geometry: 209, …}
properties: {id: 25, geom: "0103000020110F0000010000001100000087107C45F81B73C1…1000000000000000087107C45F81B73C10000000000000000", featurecla: "Admin-0 country", scalerank: 0, labelrank: 4, …}
extent: 4096
type: 3
_pbf: Pbf {buf: Uint8Array(8490050), pos: 124896, type: 2, length: 8490050}
_geometry: 209
_keys: (98) ["id", "geom", "featurecla", "scalerank", "labelrank", "sovereignt", "sov_a3", "adm0_dif", "level", "type", "admin", "adm0_a3", "geou_dif", "geounit", "gu_a3", "su_dif", "subunit", "su_a3", "brk_diff", "name", "name_long", "brk_a3", "brk_name", "brk_group", "abbrev", "postal", "formal_en", "formal_fr", "name_ciawf", "note_adm0", "note_brk", "name_sort", "name_alt", "mapcolor7", "mapcolor8", "mapcolor9", "mapcolor13", "pop_est", "pop_rank", "gdp_md_est", "pop_year", "lastcensus", "gdp_year", "economy", "income_grp", "wikipedia", "fips_10_", "iso_a2", "iso_a3", "iso_a3_eh", "iso_n3", "un_a3", "wb_a2", "wb_a3", "woe_id", "woe_id_eh", "woe_note", "adm0_a3_is", "adm0_a3_us", "adm0_a3_un", "adm0_a3_wb", "continent", "region_un", "subregion", "region_wb", "name_len", "long_len", "abbrev_len", "tiny", "homepart", "min_zoom", "min_label", "max_label", "ne_id", "wikidataid", "name_ar", "name_bn", "name_de", "name_en", "name_es", "name_fr", "name_el", "name_hi", "name_hu", "name_id", "name_it", "name_ja", "name_ko", "name_nl", "name_pl", "name_pt", "name_ru", "name_sv", "name_tr", "name_vi", "name_zh", "geom", "b2d"]
_values: (2137) [25, "0106000020E610000002000000010300000001000000530400…040D52359FCE41B4038BB4DFC74304DC040A976AE71E31B40", "Admin-0 country", 0, 4, "Guyana", "GUY", 2, "Sovereign country", "Guy.", "GY", "Co-operative Republic of Guyana", 3, 1, 8, 737718, 11, 6093, 2017, 2002, 2016, "6. Developing region", "4. Lower middle income", -99, "328", 23424836, "Exact WOE match as country", "South America", "Americas", "Latin America & Caribbean", 6, 0, 4, 9, 1159320817, "Q734", "غيانا", "গায়ানা", "Γουιάνα", "गयाना", "ガイアナ", "가이아나", "Gujana", "Guiana", "Гайана", "圭亚那", "0103000020110F0000010000001100000087107C45F81B73C1…1000000000000000087107C45F81B73C10000000000000000", "BOX(-20037508.3427892 0,0 20037508.3427892)", 23, "0106000020E610000015000000010300000001000000E70100…0A0CD7493FE8145408058EA72ADF01840985ECF35DE824540", "France", "FR1", "Country", "FRA", "Fr.", "F", "French Republic", 7, 5, 9, 67106161, 16, 2699000, "1. Developed region: G7", "1. High income: OECD", "FR", "-99", "250", -90, 23424819, "Includes only Metropolitan France (including Corsica)", "Europe", "Western Europe", "Europe & Central Asia", 1.7, 6.7, 1159320637, "Q142", "فرنسا", "ফ্রান্স", "Frankreich", "Francia", "Γαλλία", "फ़्रान्स", "Franciaország", "Perancis", "フランス", "프랑스", "Frankrijk", "Francja", "França", "Франция", "Frankrike", "Fransa", "Pháp", "法国", 24, "0106000020E610000001000000010300000001000000E10200…08001834E4F7A0A4058D7C0CD570A4BC0C0FE35A279790A40", "Suriname", "SUR", …]
geometry: (3) [Array(154), Array(5), Array(4)]
__proto__: Object
```

I'd like to style based on one of the properties/keys. I use the below for mapping geojsons and styling them as a canvas, but I seem unable do the same with `L.vectorGrid.protobuf` . I've had a look at [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/master/docs/demo-points.html) but I'm not sure how to get it to style with my dataset.

```
stylesMapping = {
"MARPOL":  {color: "#AB767F", weight: 1.5, opacity: 0.7},
"Sea Area Boundary":  {color: "pink", weight: 1.5, opacity: 0.7},
}

function CanvasVTLayer (GJson){
  //console.log(GJson)
  layer = L.vectorGrid.slicer(GJson, {
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,//L.svg.tile,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
      sliced: function(properties) {
        return stylesMapping[properties.TYPE]
      }
    },
    interactive: false
    });
    return layer
}
```

Any suggestions on how to style?

Stay safe all.

Comment: I'm no `L.vectorGrid` plugin expert, but I would say say that `getFeatureId` option function should return value `f.properties.id`.